# Get all column value like ID = @ID, value = @value applicable for all column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update my column so that my output should like 
ID=@ID, Value=@value, data=@data

I don't know abjectly how to get this type of output but i tried something LEN property

```
declare @tmp varchar(250) SET @tmp = '@'
select @tmp = @tmp + COLUMN_NAME + ',@' FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE TABLE_NAME ='tbl_emp'
select SUBSTRING(@tmp,0,LEN(@tmp)-1) as ColumnName
```

My column contain Multiple data here i am shearing some data ID, Value, Data and so on i want something like  ID=@ID, Value=@value, data=@data in horizontal line is it possible if yes then please guide me

i tried something like this

```
declare @tmp varchar(250) SET @tmp = ' '
select COLUMN_NAME + '=@' +COLUMN_NAME + ',  ' FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE TABLE_NAME ='tbl_emp'
```

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of the [question you asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57873858/i-want-to-add-symbol-before-my-all-column-values)?

Comment: its similar but not same actually i am new in so

Comment: my output should like that  ID=@ID, Value=@value, data=@data

Comment: All your questions are just pieces of the bigger question you asked yesterday. You don't want to roll your own procedures like this. It is full of pitfalls.

Comment: sorry for that but next time i will remember

Comment: No...I mean you are continuing to develop something that you really shouldn't. You should consider looking into an ORM to help you. Rolling your own CRUD procedures for every table has lots and lots of challenges that don't seem obvious at first.

Comment: @SeanLange i tried but at last i hopeless so i asked but from today onward i ll try my self at last

Comment: Not a problem at all asking very detailed and focused questions. My concern is that what you are trying to do is going to backfire on you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
declare @tmp varchar(250) SET @tmp = ''
select @tmp = @tmp + CASE WHEN @tmp <> '' THEN ', ' ELSE @tmp END + COLUMN_NAME + '=@' +  COLUMN_NAME  FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE TABLE_NAME ='tbl_emp'
select @tmp as ColumnName
```